# Javascript or jquery to replace text in A tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Example:

```
    <a href=''>Hello</a>
```

I want to replace the string "Hello" in all  A tags  to 'Not Good' using jquery or Javascript.

the result like this:

```
    <a href=''>Not Good</a>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: $('a').text('Not Good'); is good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to replace the string "Hello" in all A tags to 'Not Good'

Assuming that "Hello" is not the only content of the `a` element, but that it contains only text:

```
$("a").text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace('Hello', 'Not Good');
});
```

If there are multiple occurrences of "Hello" in the same `a` element, use a regular expression (`/Hello/g`) instead of a simple string.

Reference: [`$.fn.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1):

use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/). you can just do:

```
$("a").html("Not Good");
//or
$("a").text("Not Good");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 $("a").text("Not Good");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "Hello"){
        $(this).text("Not Good");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/MbkU5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try something.

```
$('a').text('Not Good');
```

Try this [**LINK**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

you can specify an id for that link and then change its text. it will avoid replacing the text of other hyper links.

```
  <a id="hello" href=''>Hello</a>
  $("#hello").html("Not Good");
           or
  $("#hello").text("Not Good");
```